# Scale div as long as body and sub sub div scroll

Tags: css

I have this CSS problem I never encountered before.
I have a div (bs-pane) at the right of the page which should be as high as the body (without counting itself). So far that works on my project . Inside that bs-pane I have a sub-sub div (#bsresults) that when it is much too long, has to scroll.
  But nothing works.
Strangely enough the bs-pane height is as long as the content on my projects (with waaaay more css), and it's only the #bsresults that I have problems with. Spent hours on it and I'm stuck.
Any help appreciated.

```
#bs-pane {
min-width: 30em;
box-sizing: border-box;
position: absolute;
top: 80px;
right: 0;
z-index: 9000;
background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
box-shadow: -0.3em 0.3em 0.5em;
border-radius: 5px;
max-width: 50vw;
font-size: small;
font-family: arial,sans-serif;
max-height: calc(100% - 80px);
background-color:blue;
}
#bs-pane #bsresults {
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
height: inherit;
padding: 2em;
background-color: hsla(24,80%,80%,0.5);
max-height: inherit;
}
```

Here is the full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3tqs6n0p/
Explained in other words: The blue/purple div bottom should end at the last "Blablabla" and the yellow div should stay inside that and scroll.
Problem is of course width the height of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like that:

```css
#bs-pane {
  min-width: 30em;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: absolute;
 top: 80px;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 9000;
 background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
 box-shadow: -0.3em 0.3em 0.5em;
 border-radius: 5px;
 max-width: 50vw;
 font-size: small;
 font-family: arial,sans-serif;
 max-height: calc(100vh - 80px); /* change from 100% */
  background-color:blue;
  overflow-y:scroll; /* added */
}
#flextitle {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 position: absolute; /* changed from fixed */
 right: 0;
 background: white;
 padding: 1.5em 1em 2em 0em;
  background-color:red;
  height:4rem;
  width:10rem;
}
#bs-pane #bsresults {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 height: inherit;
 padding: 2em;
  background-color: hsla(24,80%,80%,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div>
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
</div>
<div>
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
</div>
<div>
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
</div>
<div>
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
</div>
<div>
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
</div>
<div>
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
</div>
<div>
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
</div>
<div>
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
</div>
<div>
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
</div>
<div>
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
Blabla bla blablablable<br>
Bluebleeblaie bleak freak shot me sjeik
</div>
</div>
<div id="bs-pane">
<div id="flextitle">
flextitle, fixed division
</div>
<div id="bsbelowtit">
 <div id="bsresults">
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  <div>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text   Some text <br>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, the bs-pane should be (almost) as high as the black-on-white text.. In other words the bottom of bs-pane should be at the last line of "Bluebleeblaie.." (black/white).
Thanls for trying.